# How can I add function name as route in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.7

I have a controller which returns enums for respective fields. e.g.

```
// Expected route - /api/getFamilyTypes - only GET method is allowed
public function getFamilyTypes()
{
    return [
        'Nuclear Family',
        'Joint Family'
    ];
}
```

I've around 20 functions like this. How can I add this without manually adding an entry per function in routes file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can update with some of those functions ? any patterns ?

Answer (score 2):

In your routes file, add something like this,

```
Route::get('/something/{func}', 'SomeController@functionRoute');
```

Where `something` is whatever path you're wanting to use and `SomeController` is the controller with the 20 functions you're using and `functionRoute` is the action that we're about to make.

Then in your controller, make a function like this,

```
public function functionRoute($func)
{
    return $this->$func();
}
```

This will make it so that whenever someone browses to `/something/*` on your website, it'll execute the function name at the end. So if you navigate to `/something/getFamilyTypes` it'll run your `getFamilyTypes` function.

This isn't particularly secure. If you do this, the user will be able to run any of the controller's methods. You could set up a blacklist like this.

```
public function functionRoute($func)
{
    $blacklist = [
        'secret',
        'stuff',
    ];
    return in_array($func, $blacklist) ? redirect('/') : $this->$func();
}
```

Or you could set up a whitelist like this,

```
public function functionRoute($func)
{
    $whitelist = [
        'getFamilyTypes',
        'otherUserFriendlyStuff',
    ];
    return in_array($func, $whitelist) ? $this->$func() : redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Calling `$this->$func()` on untrusted user input is likely to be unsafe. It allows _any_ method on the controller to be called with no arguments -- even potentially some internal methods that were never intended to be user-invokable.

Comment: Sure, but it shouldn't be a problem so long as Ganesh only has methods in that controller that they want users to have access to. I was just giving them what they asked for--"How can I add this without manually adding an entry per function in routes file?" It would be more secure if they had a whitelist of acceptable input, but at that point then why not just add them all to `api.php`?

Comment: Keep in mind that "any method" really means **any** method -- even private Laravel methods which are provided by roles. I don't immediately see anything in Laravel core which would be a risk, but I can't definitively say that it would be safe either.

Comment: I've edited it to add instructions for blacklisting and whitelisting.

Answer (score 1):

If the responses are always from hard-coded arrays (as opposed to being from a database) then one way might be to have a variable in your route:

```
Route::get('/api/enum/{field}', 'EnumController@getField');
```

And then in your controller method, use the variable to get the correct data from a keyed array:

```
public function getField($field)
{
    $fields = [
        'family' => [
            'Nuclear Family',
            'Joint Family'
        ],
        // ...
    ];

    return $fields[$field];
}
```

If you want to continue using different methods for every field then Michael's answer is the easiest option, with one caveat. Allowing users to call any method by name on your controller is a **security risk**. To protect yourself, you should *[validate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-in)* the method name against a whitelist.

Comment: It's actually a trait. I've used this in migrations file & want to use this in the front-end.